# How do I use #{request.contextPath} when the context root is, well, root: "/"?

Tags: jsf-2, el

We are currently moving an EE6 / JSF application from a deployment path `someserver.com/app` to its own subdomain `app.someserver.com`.

Most things are working smoothly, but we have had unexpected troubles with how the web layer handles the now basically nonexistent context-root.

One thing we found and fixed early was that a cookie we set had its path shortened from `"/app"` to `""`, and thus was only readable per folder on the server, not for the entire application.

We have now found a similar problem with hyperlinks that we generate in JSF:

```
<a href="#{request.contextPath}">Go to home page</a>
```

This was previously rendered as `href="/app"` and worked fine, but now with `href=""` the link is understandably no longer active. I want it to say `href=""/"`.

**Is there an elegant solution for that?**

Keep in mind that we also have links of the form

```
<a href="#{request.contextPath}/projects">Go to projects page</a>
```

, so simply replacing the empty context path with `"/"` is not good enough.

Am I missing something obvious? I saw an explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443205/pagecontext-request-contextpath-works-fine-local-but-shows-blank-live) (which matches what we experience), but no elaboration on possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't thinking clearly. I was so focused on fixing the string that `#{request.contextPath}` produces, that I missed that I basically used it wrong the entire time.

The simplest solution is to just use

```
<a href="#{request.contextPath}/">...</a>
```

(with a trailing slash) to get to the root of the application, and never use `href="#{request.contextPath}"` without a slash at all.

This solves both cases. If the application is deployed to "some_folder", the link becomes `"some_folder/"`. And if the application is deployed to the server root, then the link becomes `"/"`.

Hope this helps someone who stumbled into the same trap.